# Gedit external tools store variable for use it in other external tool

Tags: bash, shell, gedit

I want to create two external tools, one for encrypt using gpg and the other for decrypt. I will encrypt using simetric AES, so I should  prompt the password. 
I want to prompt the password only one time because if I want to encrypt or decrypt more than one time each time the password will be prompt all times that I do this operation. 
So I want to store the password to a variable. 
So, one external tool will be set password using:

```
#!/bin/sh
PASSWD="$(zenity --password --title=Authentication)\n"
```

And then the external tools one for encrypt and the other for decrypt.

My question if I can share the stored variable PASSWD between the other tools, and if it is secure way to do it. Where it will be stored.

If I use:

```
export $PASSWD
```

When this variable will be erased? Everybody could acces to it?

Thanks!

Comment: Say you're on Linux, then the environment will be visible in `/proc/<pid>/environ` with mode 400. Not a good idea.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that the `gpg-agent` is for.